# perl validate data structure syntax

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures, hash, syntax

i have configuration files for my scripts containing huge data structures, e.g:

```
foo  =>  'bar',
one  =>  'two',
bla  =>  [
           'something',
           'else',
         ],
bli  =>  {
           here  =>  {
                       'and'  => 'there',
                       'also' => 'here',
                     },
         },
etc.
```

i'm loading these configuration files using a simple e.g. :

```
%hash = do 'config.file';
```

my problem is : when users modify this configuration file, they can mess it up, forgetting a comma, bracket or anything else, it can have terrible impacts as the variables will appear empty afterwards in the script (i don't want to check for the presence of every variable..)

is there any way to "validate" the syntax of such a file/structure at loading time or right after loading it ? any module doing this ?

i suppose i could add a value at the bottom and check for the presence of this value but it's a bit dirty.

thank you !

Comment: Make sure to pass either an absolute path or `'./config.file'` to `do` (absolute path recommended, so it doesn't depend on your current directory - you can base it on the [source file path](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::This)). If you `do 'config.file'` it will search for `config.file` in `@INC` which accidentally works in older perls but surely isn't what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Is this supposed to be readable with Perl? (then shouldn't there be a comma after the `b1` entry?) Then the way to validate it is pass it to [`eval`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#eval) and then check the value of [`$@`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#$EVAL_ERROR). The less insecure way is to format your configuration in another popular, readable, writeable, comprehendable data serialization format. The [`JSON`](http://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) format meets those criteria.

Comment: indeed, i've pasted a wrong example (forgot commas myself, nice catch), will edit it. thanks.
i will try the eval method thanks, and i was thinking of another format as well, will check JSON but i wanted to avoid having to use many modules and stick to plain Perl when possible, to shorten the code.

Comment: The best approach would be writing and interface perl code to modify your configuration file. Your user could see a question and provide simple answer by typing value, your code would store result in predefined format. In this case you can store the configuration file in any format you consider fit for your task.

Comment: i like this idea (as we cannot rewrite the config file format due to the fact that too many programs/scripts are using it now), will give it a try as well, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

[Rx](http://rx.codesimply.com/) is intended to validate the schema of JSON/YAML documents but because it runs on the in-memory data structure rather than the file it's usable with arbitrary config file formats. (It also means that it can't make certain distinctions like the use of `true` vs. `1` in YAML/JSON.)